# Bayes' rule and multiple conditioning

Tags: bayesian

I know I am missing something here, so this is my question:

My textbook (Probabilistic Robotics, p.17) trivially states that Bayes' rule gives:

$ p(x |y,z) = \frac{p(y |x, z)p(x|z)}{p(y|z)} $

Are there some conditionig rule in probability that easily lets you arrive there from the simple Bayes' rule?:

$ p(x |y) = \frac{p(y |x)p(x)}{p(y)} $

B/c for me to even get close to something similar I have to do:

$$ p(x | z,y) = \frac{ p(y,z|x) p(x)} {p(y,z)}      $$
$$ = \frac{ \frac{p(y|x)p(z|x)p(x)}{p(z)} } { \frac{p(y,z)}{p(z)}  }$$
$$ = \frac{p(x|z)p(y|x)}{p(y|z)} $$
Where I had to use that y and z are conditionally independent...

So what am I missing?

Comment: One helpful "trick": Note that in your conditional expressions, there is always conditioning on $z$. Drop $z$ completely to get simpler-looking formulas first ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the definition of conditional probability: $P(x|y) = P(x,y)/P(y)$

Comment: I don't understand how that answers my question...?

Comment: Well, $$P(x|y,z) = \frac{P(x,y,z)}{P(y,z)} = \frac{P(y|x,z)P(x,z)}{P(y,z)} = \frac{P(y|x,z)P(x|z)P(z)}{P(y|z)P(z)} = \frac{P(y|x,z)P(x|z)}{P(y|z)}$$

You asked what you were missing...